# Bootstrap form not sending post data

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I've written the form below to send some data from the select boxes but I've found out that the only thing that's received by django on the completion url is the csrf token.

Here's my form:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{% url 'movie_results' %}">{% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Select Cinema</label>

            <div class="col-xs-10">
               <select id="cinema" class=" form-control">
                  <option></option>
                  {% for node in venues %}
                  <option class="" value="{{ node.slug }}">{{ node.name }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}

                </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-2 text-right">
                <label for="inputPassword3" class="control-label">Select Movie</label>
                <img class="movie-gif hidden" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}kb/images/ajax-loader.gif" style="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <select id="movie2" class=" form-control">
                  <option></option>


                </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-2 text-right">
                <label for="inputPassword3" class="control-label">Select Date</label>
                <img class="date-gif hidden" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}kb/images/ajax-loader.gif" style="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <select id="dates" class=" form-control">
                  <option></option>


                </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="movies-button" class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <button type="submit" id="find-show" class="btn btn-danger">FIND SHOW TIMES</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

And here's my view, I've checked the post data and all i get is the csrf token. I can confirm there's post request since the variables are only calculated if there's a post request.

```
def search(request, template_name='mobile/movies_search.html'):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cinema = request.POST.get('cinema','None')
        movie = request.POST.get('movie2','None')
        post = request.POST
    today = datetime.date.today()
    qs = Show.objects.filter(starts__gte=today)
    if cinema and cinema != "None":
        qs = qs.filter(venue__slug=cinema)
    if movie and  movie != "None":
        qs = qs.filter(movie__name=movie)
    if date and  date != "None":
        day,month,year = date.split('-')
        qs = qs.filter(starts__year = year, starts__day = day, starts__month=month, )
    movies = list(set([x.movie for x in qs]))
    context['movies'] = movies
    context['movie'] = movie
    context['cinema'] = cinema
    context['post'] = post

    return render_to_response(template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<select>` elements need to have a `name` property, not just an `id`. The name is what becomes the parameter name that gets submitted with the form. For example, your first `<select>` should look like this:

```
<select name="cinema" id="cinema" class=" form-control">
    ...
</select>
```